# How to connect SQL server beta (Google Cloud) to Google API engine (Node.js)

Tags: sql, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have a node.js API that is using SQL server beta from Google Cloud SQL. Works fine when testing locally and connecting directly via IP.

I deployed the API on Google APP Engine and works fine less the connection to the database. Now, what will be the server connection string to connect directly from the project API to Google cloud - SQL server beta. How I can make use of instance connection name?  (Note: Cloud SQL Admin API is enabled for this project)

I found many examples to connect for mySQL instances, but none to an SQL beta.

Comment: It might be no option to connect from App Engine. In google documnetation the SQL Server is disabled...    https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to connect SQL server beta (Google Cloud) to Google API engine (Node.js) ?

As Eugen point out, Cloud SQL instance that are using SQL server **are still in beta** and therefore, many features are not yet available.

As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) there's still no option to connect to a Cloud SQL SQL server instance from App Engine. Neither it seems to exist options to connect from external application such as Kubernetes or Compute Engine, as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app).

Nonetheless, you could try to connect to your SQL server instance by using the Cloud SQL proxy to do local testing, as shown [here.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/quickstart-proxy-test)

Then, you could try to use some node.js library that can act as a `node.js` library, as [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) for example, but I can not confirm that I will work within App Engine.

Nonetheless, if you have the option, I highly recommend you to use Cloud SQL instance using MySQL or PostgreSQL since they support connection from App Engine apps, as seen [here.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I start changing my code to use MySQL, seems to be the easy way for me. Stupid of me not check before.

Comment: FYI, here's an example of how to connect a C# app to a MySQL instance using the Cloud SQL Proxy: [https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#dotnet](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#dotnet)